# Applying Markov's Inequality and Chebyshev to bound a r.v.

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

Hi there, it's all nice and simple to work out the expectation of $X$ (which is $\mathbb{E}[X]=9$), of $X^2$ (which is $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=91$), and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = 10$. So we can apply Markov to the probability of X>50.

However, if I try to apply Markov to the probability of $X^2>50$, I get a value that is greater than 1. Does this mean Markov cannot bound this r.v.?

How do I apply Chebyshev to this, do I just take away the mean from $X^2$ and proceed like that?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You may want to apply it to $\{X^2 > 50^2\}$ -- this is perhaps a more intuitive interpretation of the question, capturing the same event as $\{X>50\}$. Note that the average value of $X^2$ (expectation) is $91$, so Markov will not give you anything for $\{X^2 > 50\}$: the probability that a r.v. $Z$ is greater than something strictly less than its mean is not addressed by Markov's inequality.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. For chebyshev should I minus the mean from both sides of the inequality?

Comment: Just apply the inequality directly: remember that Chebyshev gives $$\mathbb{P}\{ X > \mathbb{E}[X] + t \} \leq \frac{\operatorname{Var} X}{t^2}.$$ In your case, $\operatorname{Var} X = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = 91-9^2 =10$, and $t=\dots$...